# Titanium Appcelerator parse Youtube JSON with API

Tags: javascript, json, youtube-api, titanium, appcelerator

I did a research over the forums and i got confused. My demo project was created with Alloy MVC. I want to parse a JSON from Youtube API with the top releated videos of Cooking for example, and show them in a TableView.
Can anyone give me instructions how to do it?
I'm a newcomer.

This is my code what i've done so far:

Videos XML

```
<Alloy>
<Window class="container">
<View id="main" onClick="youtubeFeed">
   <Label class="header">YouTube Channel</Label>
            <TableView id="results">

            </TableView>            
        </View>
    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

Videos.js

```
function youtubeFeed () {

var apiKey = 'MY_API_KEY';
var perPage = 6;
var search = "Cooking";
var description;
var val;
var id;
var category = "News";

var query = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=search&maxResults=per_page&videoCategoryId=category&safesearch=strict&key=apikey';
var response = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

require("/api").create({
    url: query,
    type: "GET",
    success: onSuccess,
    error: onError
});

function onSuccess(e){
    console.log(e.data);
}

function onError(e){
    console.log("error");
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to call the actual API url with the help of xhr. For the beginning have a look at https://github.com/m1ga/titanium-libraries/blob/master/api.js

Create a lib folder in your projectname/app/ folder and place the js file there and then call it like this inside yor function:

```
require("/api").create({
    url: query,
    type: "GET",
    success: onSuccess,
    error: onError
});

function onSuccess(e){
    console.log(e.data);
}

function onError(e){
    console.log("error");
}
```

and make sure your query string is right. It looks like you've took a php example because it uses $ and a . at the end to concatenate.

Comment: Thank you very much for the fast response. I'd also modified my query string as you mentioned, because i used a php example. Unfortunately i didn't get it to work.

Comment: it would help if you tell us what the error is or where you got stuck

Comment: I got no errors but nothing appears when i run it on emulator. Sorry for the stupid question. Do i need something else to parse the JSON to the TableView that i have in my XML?

Comment: a lot is still missing. Have a look at http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.TableView there is some code how to create tableviewrows and hhow to add them. You should see the content of the api-response in the output-console to check if the api call is working

Answer (score 3):

You've got your JSON answer from Youtube API, now that **Miga** and **Rene** gave you hints.
There are some [guides](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/implementation/search) you might want to read to know how you're JSON object looks like when coming back from Youtube (use their API explorer).

Reading from [Titanium.UI.TableView](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.TableView) documentation, you should add a `TableViewRow` for each element in `response.items`:

```
for (var i=0; i<response.items.length; i++){
    var video, row, videoTitle;

    video = response.items[i];

    row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
        width: Ti.UI.FILL,
        height: 100
    }),

    videoTitle = Ti.UI.createLabel({
        text: video.snippet.title,
        videoId: video.id.videoId, // custom prop
        width: Ti.UI.SIZE,
        height: 80
    });
    row.add(videoTitle);

    $.results.appendRow(row);
}
```

Listen for `click` events from your `TableView` so that you can open a new controller to play a specified video:

```
$.results.addEventListener('click', function onClick(event) {
    var row = event.row,
        videoId = row.videoId;
    // TODO...
});
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what library you use to fetch a JSON, but parsing JSON doesn't work before you fetch it anways.

This is a basic example of how it should work:

```
var url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=search&maxResults=per_page&videoCategoryId=category&safesearch=strict&key=apikey';
var xhr = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient({
    onload: function() {
        var response = JSON.parse(this.responseData);
        // you've got your JSON here, after the API call succeeded
    },
    timeout: timeout
});
xhr.open('GET', url);
xhr.send();
```